# Passing complex type to windows service with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows service and winform front end app.  I need to be able to call and pass data round trip to methods in the service.  I have accomplished this by defining an interface and can pass strings without issue.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStringReverser
{
    [DataContractFormat]
    [OperationContract]
    string ReverseString(string value);
}
```

I am now trying to return a complex data type and have altered the code as such:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStringReverser
{
    [DataContractFormat]
    [OperationContract]
    DTO ReverseString(string value);
}

[Serializable]
public class DTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My implementation is as such:

```
public class StringReverser : IStringReverser
{
    public DTO ReverseString(string value)
    {
        char[] retVal = value.ToCharArray();
        int idx = 0;
        for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            retVal[idx++] = value[i];

        var dto = new DTO();
        dto.Name = retVal.ToString();
        dto.Id = 122;
        return dto;
    }
}
```

I am not particular how the data gets transferred.  I am getting an error:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter [http://tempuri.org/:ReverseStringResult](http://tempuri.org/%3aReverseStringResult). The InnerException message was ''EndElement' 'ReverseStringResult' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_Id_x003E_k__BackingField'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

In the winform I am creating the connection with this:

```
private IStringReverser pipeProxy;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ChannelFactory<IStringReverser> httpFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(
              new BasicHttpBinding(),
              new EndpointAddress(
                "http://localhost:8000/Reverse"));

        ChannelFactory<IStringReverser> pipeFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              new EndpointAddress(
                "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

        //IStringReverser httpProxy = httpFactory.CreateChannel();
        pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

I don't understand the error message or how to correct it.  How do I define how it gets deserialized?  Is the serialization ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Data Contracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class DTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That solves the error but the data I get is empty meaning Id is 0 and Name is null

Comment: I even moved the DTO object to field of the StringReverser class thinking it might be out of scope but that did not resolve.

Comment: I suggest that you fall all the way back. Replace your code that fills the DTO from the database (or wherever) with dummy code that just does something like `DTO dto = new DTO{Id=1,Name="John"};return dto;` You might also try debugging.

Comment: That is obviously part of the issue - I don't know how to debug it since it is in a windows service and has to be installed and started.  I also initialized the object as suggested and get the same empty results.

Comment: If you return constant data, and receive no data, then you're not receiving the data you returned, and should wonder whether you're even calling the service. Are you restarting the Windows Service after each build? You can use Debug->Attach to Process to debug the windows Service.

Comment: It was working fine with a return value of string.  I ensured that that the mechanism was correct there before altering the return value to a simple complex object (interesting term).  Returning it back to string works therefor my perplexity.

Comment: I run it as attached as suggested.  The value being sent is correct (populated).  The value on the received end is empty.  I am at a loss.

Comment: And yes I am restarting (even uninstalling and reinstalling) the service.

Comment: It may be time to use Fiddler or something to look at the data on the wire. Alternatively, turn on WCF Message Logging. This sounds like a namespace difference. Have you updated your Service Reference since you stopped returning `string`? Maybe the client is still expecting `string`.